# HTML CSS background-image property does not work at all

Tags: html, css, background-image, image-scaling

Ok so I am making a website which has a large background image with some text over it at the top. I have previously used just an `<img>` tag, but is scales terribly on mobile leaving the entire image still present but just handing off to the right side of the screen.

To solve this, I found a tutorial by w3schools (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_full_page.asp) which shows you can set the background to an image. I have tried this css and put it on a `<div>` but I cannot get the image to actually show up.

This is my css which should show the image.

```css
background-image: url("home background image.png");
height: 100%;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
align-content: center;
```

I have moved the image into the root folder of the site and it still doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I have located the solution! The image was set to be very small and was being covered by the navbar my site has.

My solution was to change the height from 100% to 55vw.

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1):

These properties are when you use `background: url('path_of_our_image);` on an element (like a div and not an img).

Comment: I should have said that I am using the above css on a div, not image

Comment: And did you add background: url?
Can we have a code snippet to identify the issue?

Comment: `.backgroundImage {
 background-image: url("home background image.png");
 
 height: 100%; 
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 align-content: center;
}`

Comment: And does your div has enough width ? (if you can try it on a jsfiddle maybe)

Comment: The image doesn't show at all, its just white space

Comment: using spaces in file names (like your "home background image.png") is a rather unreliable approach - the spaces will get converted to special entities - or not... Try to change the filename for example to "home_background_image.png" and use that.

Comment: As we dont have the root or structure of your project we cannot tell if url is correctly set

Comment: The css and .png are in the same directory.